# Is there a way to get the absolute line number in Bash, regardless of context?

Tags: bash, shell

In Bash (and other shells) you can get the relative line number by expanding the `LINENO` variable.

In a script without functions, this gives you the absolute line number, within a function the line number relative to the function.

Is there some way to get the line number regardless of context, i.e. the line number in the file?

Comment: I don't think so. `${FUNCNAME[0]}` is the current function, so you can know which function the line number is relative to.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in Bash 5.0.16(1) or in 3.2.57(1). `$LINENO` returns the line number in the script as expected.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing, but you could consider running with xtrace (`set -x` or run via `bash -x`) in order to see far more context. It's not exactly a debugger with line numbers, but it's a pretty good start. It won't track certain builtins, so I recommend beginning loops with commands like `: "this is a comment visible only with xtrace"`

Comment: Can you please include steps to reproduce?